# PDO DBLIB SQL Server Unicode issue

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

When I insert data to SQL Server, latin letters are added as interrogative characters.

Tried lots of ways, but none was helped. Cannot use `N` prefix with pdo, when use placeholders. Any working ways to set Unicode in pdo?

I tried:

1. `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');`
2. `$dsn = "dblib:version=7.0;charset=UTF-8;host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";`
3. `$db->exec("set names utf8");`

Comment: You may try to change the driver (PHP Driver for SQL Server is a good alternative).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I used pdo at first. No any ways for pdo to set unicode for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solved!**

Instead of placeholders in query write question marks (?) and N prefix will work.

Example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] SET name=N?, xml_data=? WHERE id=?";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
return $result->execute(array($name, $xml, $id));
```